# Unexpected HY001: Memory allocation error after MySQL upgrade

Tags: mysql

Earlier today I upgraded a `db.t3.large` MySQL instance on AWS from `v8.0.17` to `8.0.20`.  I've seen a handful of cases where I'm seeing the error `SQLSTATE[HY001]: Memory allocation error: 1038 Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size`.  I don't expect such an error because the config or instance type didn't change.  An example of where I'm seeing this is on the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages`
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM `updates`
        WHERE
            `messages`.`update_id` = `updates`.`id`
            AND `game_id` = 18
    )
    AND `messages`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

In this query, all columns used in the `order` and `where` clauses are either foreign or primary keys with `messages.deleted_at` being the only exception.

In the meantime I'm going to adjust this setting in my prod environment to increase the size of the `sort_buffer_size`, but this change is not recommend according to a lot of stuff I'm reading so I hope it'll temporarily resolve the issue.

Comment: this looks like a bug, try to update ti 8.0.23

Comment: I was originally on 8.0.23 but I was running into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67255202/mysql-upgrade-causing-unexpected-results-on-simple-where-clauses so I had to downgrade because I couldn't figure out what was going on there.

Comment: i followed that thead but you didn't post the result of tosql

Comment: have checked all the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you have large JSON or Geometry columns?  (Always provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` when asking a question.)

Either increase or decrease `sort_buffer_size` and `innodb_sort_buffer_size`.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103465
and
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103225

Comment: Bingo, you're 100% correct, than you!

Comment: Flag those bugs so that they understand that the bug should be fixed, not swept under the rug.

Comment: After running into several issues, and buffer size tweaks causing memory issues on our database, rather than upgrading our RDS instance we've decided to accept a brief outage and use a mysql dump of our prod db to roll back to `v8.0.17`.  I shared this approach on the bug report.  Thanks for your quick response to this!